# showing isolated points are most countable.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need hand in the following question.

> Where $A \subset \mathbb R$, show that the set of isolated points of A, is most countable.

My attempt was for this question, I followed the negation of definition of limit point. Then I claimed set of isolated points for $A$ is $E =\mathbb Q \cap A$. Then  if $x$ is an isolated point of $A$, s.t. $x\in E$ then for all $r>0$, if $y$ is an element of $B_r(x)$, then we must have $x=y$.

To prove this I take for any $p/q$ element of $E$, $p$ and $q$ is integers such that with no common factors, then when we take $r= 1/q$, in ball $B_r(p/q)$, we only have $p/q$. I am wondering if this method is true. Or Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: By the Archimedean Property we have for all real numbers $x$ there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<x$. Thus taking $$x=\frac{p}{q}+\frac{1}{q}$$ we see that there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} \in B_r \left( \frac{p}{q} \right)$.

Comment: Consider $A = \{\sqrt{2}\}$. This set contains only one point, so certainly that point is isolated. But $\mathbb Q \cap A$ is empty. Your idea to consider rational numbers is good, though. Note that for every isolated point $x \in A$, there is some open interval that contains $x$ but no other point of $A$. Now show that this implies that there exists an injection from the set of isolated points of $A$ to $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: In general $B_r(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb R$ and $r >0$ is uncountable.